# How does displaying ads on open source project hosted on CodePlex work?

Tags: open-source, ads

I have an open source project on [CodePlex](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Start%20a%20Project&referringTitle=home#Ads). Today I went to "Edit Project Summary & Details" page to make some modification.  I noticed a new [check box "Use Advertisements from The Lounge"](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Start%20a%20Project&referringTitle=home#Ads).

I just wonder if anyone takes advantage of display ads on CodePlex?

How does it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently about 1000 projects on CodePlex that have turned on the advertisements from The Lounge.  As soon as you turn on the checkbox, the ads immediately start showing up on your project.  You can choose to donate the proceeds to charity (through the second check box), or have the money sent to you.  To have the ad money sent to you then you contact The Lounge and provide them with your information.

Answer (score 0):

I have been a member of CodePlex for a quite a few months now and enjoy their hosting/publishing service (check out my [project](http://silverlightmsgbox.codeplex.com/)). Nevertheless, when things come to making money from the Lounge Ads, the process is very-very annoying and time-consuming. At least in my experience. I have sent and received countless emails trying to set up my account with no avail. Their response time is usually late for several days if not a week and their finance team seems to comprise of only one person. Somehow, customer emails "slip through the crack."

Anyhow, best of luck to both of us.